# Streaming on a second screen

Tags: display, streaming

There is a bug that doesn't make any sense to me, but it's so consistent that I had to ask.

I'm watching TV streaming via my cable company. It's not a good streaming service.

When I watch it on my laptop screen I have an OK quality, but as soon as I drag the window to the second screen the streaming goes from OK to really bad. I've refreshed, waited, switched channels.. Nothing works accept dragging the window back to the laptop screen.

My laptop is a `Lenovo G50-70` with `windows 10` and the screen is a `PHILIPS 227E` connected with `D-sub`

Any ideas why this happens and what can I do?

Comment: My guess is you're running into [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) working as intended.

Comment: Thanks! If you'd put it as an answer I'll accept it. Also, it there a way around this? would a streamer help maybe?

Comment: Is your graphics capabilities good enough on the laptop? if you turn off screen extend and instead disable your laptop screen and use just the second screen (as main), do you have the same problem?